# Array for loop issues

Tags: java, arrays

I have been having a problem with a program for an assigment.  The assignment is to generate a code in Java and that will allow a user to input a state, the state bird, and the state flower, then print that back out, or just exit the program.  I actually had mostly everything working perfectly with exception to writing the array.  I had the array in the method store, but would bounce back to method intro so that I could take advantage of the if statement.  That caused the loop to always reset to zero. I fixed this by adding an INT variable called COUNTER that would increment outside the method and then set the variables i,j, and k equal to it in order to fix that previous problem.  The problem, it didn't work, so I changed the program back, and no it will not access the store method, and I have no clue why.

Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class states {
    //create string in order to store state data
    int i,j,k = 0;
    String theState;
    String bird;
    String flower;
    String[][] states = new String[i][j];
    boolean intro;
    int counter = 0;
    //scanner to get data
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    //INtro method, maybe have it throw a bulean out back to other code
    public String intro ()
    {
        //System.out.println("Wlecome to this program.");
        System.out.println("Enter a state or select none to exit.");
        String initial = input.nextLine();
        if(initial.equalsIgnoreCase("None"))
        {
            this.intro = false;
            exit(initial);
            //return intro;
            return initial;
        }
        else
        {
            store(states, initial);
            this.intro = true;
            //return intro; 
            return initial;
        }
    }
    //storing data
    public void store(String a[][], String initial)
    {

        for (int i=0; i < states.length;i++)
        {
        theState = initial;
        System.out.println("Please Enter State Bird.");
        String bird = input.nextLine();

        for (int j = counter; j < states.length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println("Please Enter State Flower.");
            String flower = input.nextLine();

            for (int k = 0; j < states.length; k++)
            {
                states[i][j]="Your state is: " + theState +"Its Bird is: " + bird +"Its flower is: " + flower;
                intro(); 
            }
        }
    }
    /*states[i][j][k]=theState + " " + bird + " "+ flower;
    i++;
    j++;
    k++;
    intro();*/


}
//exit clause
/*public String toString(String a[][])
{
    String theEnd = " ";
    //print array
    for (int row = 0; row < states.length; row ++)
    {
        for(int column = 0; column < states[row].length; column ++)
        {
            for(int col = 0; col < states[row][column].length; col++)
            {
                theEnd = (states[row][column][col] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
    //exit program
    return theEnd;
}*/
public void exit(String theEnd)
{
    System.out.println(theEnd);
    for (int i = 0; i < states.length;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < states[i].length; j ++)
        {
            System.out.println(states[i][j] + " ");
        /*  for(int col = 0; col < states[row][column].length; col++)
            {
                System.out.println(states[row][column] + " ");
            }*/
        }
    }
    //exit program
    System.out.println("Thank you for using this program, Good Bye.");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: You should really try to narrow the problem down. This is a lot of code to ask people to dig through, especially since you seem to be making heavy use of side effects.

Comment: also, the "states" two-dimensional array is initialised with 0 rows and 0 columns?

Comment: Have a look at the size of the 2d-array. Notice anything about it? If it's not obvious for you from looking at the code itself, you should use a debugger.

Comment: why did you initialized the 2d-array with 0 and 0?